# Turning expression into strings

Tags: scala

I have written this function that's supposed to return strings that represent arithmetic expressions.

```
     import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object ArithEval extends ArithEvalLike {


def eval (e:Expr):Double = e match {
    case Num(a) => a
    case Exponent(a,b) => Math.pow(eval(a),eval(b))
    case Add(a,b) =>eval(a) + eval(b)
    case Sub(a,b) =>eval(a) - eval(b)
    case Mul(a,b) =>eval(a) * eval(b)
    case Div(a,b) =>eval(a) / eval(b)
   }
}


object ArithPrinter extends ArithPrinterLike {
def print (e: Expr ): String = e match {
    case Num(a) => "a"
    case Exponent(a,b) =>print(a).toString  + "^" + print(b).toString
    case Add(a,b) => print(a).toString  + "+" + print(b).toString
    case Sub(a,b) => print(a).toString  + "-" + print(b).toString
    case Mul(a,b) =>print(a).toString  + "*" + print(b).toString
    case Div(a,b) =>print(a).toString  + "/" + print(b).toString
   }
}
```

This doesn't seem correct, because some of my tests are failing.

Here are the test I ran:

scala>ArithPrinter.print(Mul(Num(2.0),Mul(Add(Num(3.0),Num(5.0)),Num(-10.0))))

It says it can't find 'Num'

I don't know if it's my tests that are wrong or the function itself.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: What are the failing test? And could you post the whole code?

Comment: Post the test code that is failing.

Comment: We can't tell without the definitions of` Num`, `Add` etc. Ifi t says "can't find Num", probably there isn't a `Num` defined (or it's the wrong type)

Answer (score 0):

```
case Num(a) => "a"
```

This looks wrong. You're just printing "a", the string. You probably want a.toString

Comment: What's your constructor for Num? You might have created a case class that takes an Int but be passing a float?